# Android: Second 180 degree rotation of imageview around Y mirrors the image

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, objectanimator

I'm trying to make an imageview rotate around it's Y axis, similar to a card flipping, but it should have the same picture on both sides.

To do this, I use an ObjectAnimator in an AnimationSet (though this happens when the Y rotation is the only animation in the set, as well as when it's combined with other animations) to rotate it from 0 to -180 around Y axis. This works fine the first time. However, if I click it again, the image will suddenly get mirrored then rotate 180 degrees around Y axis.

How come the image gets mirrored/reversed before animating? My current idea is that it retains some property, so while it first goes from 0 to -180, next time it will jump from -180 to 0, then rotate from 0 to -180 again. I'm not sure if that is the cause, however if it is, how can I work around this and prevent it from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, this happens because `ObjectAnimator` doesn't actually applies final value itself. You have to use `AnimationListener` and `onAnimationEnd` to save view's state.